# RuntimeError: result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long

Tags: pytorch, nlp, classification, bert-language-model

I know there are many errors like this solved already but mine still gives the same error no matter what I tried. I tried to fine-tune a multi-label classification model using BERT pre-train model based on this notebook [Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NKYYVSex__vde-lnYCmsRmyHjJhV6cKt?usp=sharing#scrollTo=IHgSs2icYxTn). I'm quite new to this so I can't seem to find what the issue is.

And this is my code:

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer, AutoTokenizer
from sklearn.metrics import label_ranking_average_precision_score
import torch
torch.Tensor(1)
import numpy as np

model_name = 'beomi/kcbert-base'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def preprocess_function(examples):
  tokenized_examples = tokenizer(str(examples["문장"]))
  tokenized_examples['labels'] = torch.tensor(examples["label"], dtype=torch.float)
   
  return tokenized_examples

tokenized_dataset = dataset_dict.map(preprocess_function)
tokenized_dataset.set_format(type='torch', columns=['input_ids', 'labels', 'attention_mask', 'token_type_ids'])

from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)

labeling = ['문장', '식중독', '변질', '이취/냄새', '이물질', '배송', '포장', '가격불만', '품질', '유통기한', 'clean']
num_labels=len(labeling)

model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
  model_name, 
  num_labels=num_labels, 
  problem_type="multi_label_classification"
)
model.config.id2label = {i: label for i, label in zip(range(num_labels), labeling)}
model.config.label2id = {label: i for i, label in zip(range(num_labels), labeling)}

def compute_metrics(x):
  return {
    'lrap': label_ranking_average_precision_score(x.label_ids, x.predictions),
  }

batch_size = 64
args = TrainingArguments(
  output_dir="model_output",
  evaluation_strategy="epoch",
  learning_rate=2e-5,
  per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
  per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
  num_train_epochs=10,
  save_strategy='epoch',
  load_best_model_at_end=True,
  metric_for_best_model='lrap',
  greater_is_better=True
)

trainer = Trainer(
  model=model, 
  args=args, 
  train_dataset=tokenized_dataset["train"], 
  eval_dataset=tokenized_dataset["valid"], 
  compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
  tokenizer=tokenizer,
  data_collator=data_collator,
)

trainer.train()
```

Here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21840\4032920361.py in <module>
----> 1 trainer.train()    
RuntimeError: result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long
```